# PHP: Can I pipe curl output through gunzip using built in curl functions?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, php-curl

I'm working on a script that downloads large files, decompresses them, and then parses the contents, inserting data I like into sql. I upgraded this script to work in a multi-threaded type way, where it is downloading one file, decompressing another file, and parsing another file all at once. But alas, I'm getting bottlenecked by the hard drive.

With the help of `##php`, I realized I can use the following command to pipe output of `curl` directly to `gunzip` to cut my disk i/o in half (excluding SQL):

> curl https://example.com/path/to/large_file.gz | gunzip -c > /large_temp_files/large_file

Tested and confirmed, this method writes the uncompressed data directly to disk without writing compressed data first.

So my question is, is there any way I can pipe the data like that using php's build in `curl` functions?

For regular files, you can open a file pointer and set that pointer as one of the `curl_setopt` options, to download the file to disk rather setting the data to a variable.

These are 5 GB files so that's not going to work. All my other code uses the built in functions for my http requests, so I'd like to stick with doing it that way if possible, for consistency and readability.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't actually tested this, but i assume this is possible by using a custom CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION with inflate_init() & co, something like

```
$decompressor = inflate_init(ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE);
$fp = fopen("decompressed", "wb");
$ch = curl_init("http://url.com/large_file.zip");
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => function ($ch, string $compressed) use (&$fp, &$decompressor) {
        fwrite($fp, inflate_add($decompressor, $compressed));
        return strlen($compressed);
    }
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
unset($fp,$ch,$decompressor); // don't know how to clean up the decompressor, hopefully GC will do it.
```

btw if you want to get really fancy, you could probably parse the data directly from the deflate_add() call and insert it to your SQL database without ever writing the decompressed data to disk, that may be even faster (compared to reading from harddrives, reading from ram is *VERY* fast :)  )

Comment: While reading from RAM is fast, it's good to break the process in half because the download/decompression and the parsing take about the same amount of time, so I have a multithreaded setup where those two tasks happen at the same time. Which is still much faster than if I streamed from the download, to the decompressor, to the parser all in one move. It's a good idea though. I'll poke around with the code above and see if I can get it to work. Thanks!